# Can my css affect Javascript-generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code that created a bunch of buttons at the end of an action, and I want the buttons to still apply to the css in my css, like so. CSS:

```
.buttons {
  color:red;
}
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = "<input type="button" class="buttons" />}
```

HTML

```
<html id="html"></html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply put don't worry the css effects all the elements that satisfy the selector regardless on when they are created

Answer (score 0):

A quick test would have given you the answer x-)

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="allo">world</div>';
```

```css
.allo { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="allo">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = '<input type="button" class="buttons" />'};
```

Can you try?